# Python subprocess call cannot take grep

Tags: python, jython

Python subprocess call is supposed to run as command as is, but it is complaining if there is a pipe in it. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
import time
service_name= "mysrvc"
state ="STOPPED"
mycmd ="sc query " + service_name + " " + "|" + " findstr" + " " + state 
print(mycmd)
if subprocess.call(mycmd)==0:
  print("Service stopped successfully")
```

The Error I get is :

```
ERROR: Invalid Option; Would you like to see help for the QUERY and QUERYEX commands? [ y | n ]:
```

If I change the command to just

```
mycmd = "sc query " + service_name
```

I am able to run the script successfully. It is just the pipe and the arguments following it which is a problem. If I run `sc query mysvrc | findstr STOPPED` directly on command line it works fine.

How can I get this to work? Note that I run this python script using jython2.7. I wasn't successful in using win32serviceutil because it couldn't find the module win32serviceutil.

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message into your question. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: The Error I get is : ERROR:  Invalid Option; Would you like to see help for the QUERY and QUERYEX commands? [ y | n ]:

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message --- it will get buried down here in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, [`subprocess` can't handle single `str` inputs and shell metacharacters like `|` unless `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). But in this case, you really don't need a pipe anyway. You can have Python do the filtering and avoid the pipe to `findstr` completely:

```
# sc query command only, as list which gets better safety/performance
mycmd = ["sc", "query", service_name]

# Open command to run asynchronously, capturing output
proc = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Wait for process to complete while slurping output
stdout, _ = proc.communicate()

# Check if expected output was seen and process exited successfully
if state in stdout and proc.returncode == 0:
    print("Service stopped successfully")
```

Comment: Hi! What is "state" in the code? Am getting the following error:                    if state in stdout and proc.returncode == 0:
NameError: name 'state' is not defined

Comment: Sorry.. I understaood what the state is. I added an else to "if state in stdout and proc.returncode==0" to print error. When I execute it, it is always going to the else part . I think it is not evaluating state in stdout.

Comment: I printed stdout and found that state is "STOP PENDING". Thats why it is failing. I will write a while do loop to keep querying until this changes to STOPPED. That should help

Comment: @user1164061: Glad you figured it out. :-) Wasn't at a computer to see your comments until just now.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `jython` specifically, but the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) documentation suggests that your command needs to be a list, not a string, unless you set the `shell` variable to `True`. Your code should work if you change your call to be `subprocess.call(mycmd, shell=True)`, but please be sure to read the warnings in the documentation about the security risks inherent in setting `shell` to `True`.

If you don't want to set `shell=True`, you won't be able to use the pipe directly in your command, but there is a section in the documentation, [replacing shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) on how to mimic the functionality of the pipe using `subprocess.Popen`.